# How can I make a CIF file for Monoclinic MoO2?

Tags: crystallography, cif

A CIF file of Monoclinic $\ce{MoO2}$ is not available in the  [Crystallography Open Database](http://www.crystallography.net/cod/) website. How can I make it myself or find it elsewhere?

Comment: I was guessing you used the COD. Have you tried any of the other databases in this [IUCR list](https://www.iucr.org/resources/data/databases)?

Comment: @Tyberius Thankyou Sir

Answer (score 5):

I was able to find a CIF for this compound through the [Materials Project](https://materialsproject.org/). You can download the CIF, along with viewing other properties of this structure, here: [Monoclinic MoO2](https://materialsproject.org/materials/mp-559140/)

In general, the Materials Project is a good place to look for CIFs, along with any of the databases listed by the [IUCR](https://www.iucr.org/resources/data/databases) (International Union of Crystallography).

Comment: @ Tyberius Thankyou Sir

Answer (score 3):

You can download structures freely from the database of [Materials Project](https://materialsproject.org/).

For example, the monoclinic MoO$_2$ can be found from this link:
https://materialsproject.org/materials/mp-559140/

Comment: It looks like your link is for monoclinic $\ce{MnO2}$ rather than $\ce{MoO2}$

Comment: @Jack Thankyou Sir

Comment: @Tyberius Thanks for your comments, I have fixed it.

Comment: @user4106 The previous link is related MnO$_2$ rather than MoO$_2$, you can find monoclinic MoO$_2$ from the updated link.

Comment: @Jack Yes Sir. Thankyou Sir.